# What is the ufw command to set the default policy to deny all forwarding traffic?

Tags: ufw

I tried the command `sudo ufw default deny FORWARD` but it is  not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it using `sudo ufw default deny routed`

Answering my own question as I didn't find a similar answer online.